# Create a layout with div tags and CSS

Tags: html, css, web

Im trying to create a layout for a site. I am using three div tags, the container and left and right. I want the left to be a fixed width as it will be the navigation. The right side will display the content. The right side will be loaded in from a database so the content width will need to vary depending on what is loaded. Currently the width will only display up to the width of the window and if you minimize the window the content gets cut off instead of displaying a scroll bar and allowing the user to scroll over to see the rest of the data. As well I also cant get the left and right divs to display together. At one point I had them beside each other but there was a giant gap in the middle which wasn't what I was trying to achieve. I'm just hoping for some help on how to go about achieving the layout. Cheers,

```css
<style> body {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  color: #000000;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 75px;
}
#wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #9FF;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  min-width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
.left {
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  width: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
.right {
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  padding: 15px;
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  min-width: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Schedule Design</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <p>This is some text</p>
      <p>Here is some more</p>
      <p>this is another one</p>
      <p>this on is for good measure</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <form>
        <table align="center" cellpadding="5px">
          <tr>
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just get rid of the float:right in the right div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of `float: right;` and `min-width: 400px;` from your `.right` class, you should get the right pane to stick to the left pane. Also, `overflow: auto;` will allow your right pane to scroll its width.

```css
<style> body {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  color: #000000;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 75px;
}
#wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #9FF;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  min-width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
.left {
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  width: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
.right {
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Schedule Design</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <p>This is some text</p>
      <p>Here is some more</p>
      <p>this is another one</p>
      <p>this on is for good measure</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <form>
        <table align="center" cellpadding="5px">
          <tr>
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tyler Foraie</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" />
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ok so what you have going on here is pretty close to what Im looking for except when you minimize the screen the content on the right still gets cut off and doesnt creat the scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

```
.left{ display:inline-block;}

   /* or */

 .right{ display:inline-block; }
```

the Two classes will be inlined

Comment: Please explain what this does?

Comment: the class left and right will be inlined . the left class in the left side and the right class  in the right side .

Comment: u re using the "float" but u havn't specifed the positions of your classes . you should take of  the "float" and try with display:inline-block ;